# HTTP URL Connection Timeout

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

When I hit the following URL in browser it's working perfectly:

`http://62.215.226.164/fccsms_P.aspx?UID=something&P=something&S=InfoText&G=96567771404&M=hello&L=E`

but when I try to hit the URL with the following java code it's not working:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(null, "http://62.215.226.164/fccsms_P.aspx?", new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String urlParameters="UID=something&P=something=InfoText&G=96567771404&M=hello&L=E";
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } 
     catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());   
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @SomePerson  not able to hit the url

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hit" the URL? What is the program doing _wrong_?

Comment: the program should make a http post request to the URL its not doing soo

Comment: Did it throw an exception? Is it doing something incorrectly? You really need to be more specific.

Comment: no its not thowing any exception

Comment: Well then _what exactly is it doing wrong?_ We can't read minds, you know (except Jon Skeet).

Comment: @SomePerson you realy don't need to read the mind , if you would have read the code you would have get the bug provided you are knowledgable enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a HTTP url through HttpsURLConnection. So its making problem. just change your first 2 line. You will get the proper output.

```
URL url = new URL("http://62.215.226.164/fccsms_P.aspx");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: A code dump is not a good answer.  It requires readers to compare it line by line with the original question’s code.  Explain what you changed and explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your request params first:

urlParameters="UID=something`&P=something=InfoText`&G=96567771404&M=hello&L=E";

Please post the exception stack trace here to help you better.